# React Native ios builed Failed on Mac M1

Tags: react-native, apple-m1

I created the React project version 0.66.1. It's run well on Android but not in ios.

** BUILD FAILED **
The following build commands failed:
CompileC /Users/nunggu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/The_Shop_App-cbmtjvbjevexvvefqivkzkbmmaxa/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RCT-Folly.build/Objects-normal/arm64/SysUio.o /Users/nunggu/Documents/React\ Udemy/The_Shop_App/ios/Pods/RCT-Folly/folly/portability/SysUio.cpp normal arm64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'RCT-Folly' from project 'Pods')
(1 failure)

##################################
{
"name": "the_shop_app",
"version": "0.0.1",
"private": true,
"scripts": {
"android": "react-native run-android",
"ios": "react-native run-ios",
"start": "react-native start",
"test": "jest",
"lint": "eslint ."
},
"dependencies": {
"react": "17.0.2",
"react-native": "0.66.1"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
"@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
"@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
"babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
"eslint": "7.14.0",
"jest": "^26.6.3",
"metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.66.2",
"react-test-renderer": "17.0.2"
},
"jest": {
"preset": "react-native"
}
}

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Use https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/ there are only a few new versions support the M1, but it could also be a different issue

Comment: Still got errors.

Comment: check it [react native project not build on MacBook M1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70204872/react-native-project-not-build-on-macbook-m1)

Answer (score 1):

After having tried many trials, I already found the solution.
Just add the code to the Podfile in the ios folder as follows:

```
 use_flipper!({ 'Flipper-Folly' => '2.6.0', 'Flipper' => '0.112.0', 'Flipper-RSocket' => '1.4.0' })

 post_install do |installer|
react_native_post_install(installer)
__apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)

 flipper_post_install(installer)

 find_and_replace("Pods/Headers/Private/RCT-Folly/folly/synchronization/DistributedMutex-inl.h",
 "atomic_notify_one(state)", "folly::atomic_notify_one(state)")

 find_and_replace("Pods/Flipper-Folly/folly/synchronization/DistributedMutex-inl.h",
 "atomic_wait_until(&state, previous | data, deadline)", "folly::atomic_wait_until(&state, previous | data, deadline)")

 end
end
```

Flipper compatibility version as the link:
https://cocoapods.org/pods/Flipper.